# Multiple animations after each other

Tags: iphone, ios, animation, uiimageview, mkmapview

I'm having a problem I can't find any solution for it.

So basically, I'm having a compass that I want to "pop in"/"pop out" into the view, and then start to update heading, but heading stops updating after I dismiss/pop out the compass.

Like: user wants compass-> presses button-> compass pops up-> starting to rotate compass needle-> user don't want compass anymore/dismisses compass-> compass pops out of view.

So my question is: If i make one animation, the other animation stops, how do i make it possible for both to run after each other?

In showCompass:

```
(IBAction) showCompass:

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
directionsArrow.center = CGPointMake(160, 410);
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

In locationManager:

```
float oldRadian = (-manager.heading.trueHeading * M_PI/180.0f);
float newRadian = (-newHeading.trueHeading * M_PI/180.0f);

CABasicAnimation *animation;
        animation=[CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation"];
animation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:oldRadian];
animation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:newRadian];
animation.duration = 0.5f;

[directionsArrow.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"animateMyRotation"];
directionsArrow.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(newRadian);
```

In dismissCompass:

```
-(IBAction) dismissCompass {
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
directionsArrow.center = CGPointMake(160, 410);
[UIView commitAnimations];
[locationManager stopUpdateHeading];
}
```

**New code:**
**Show:**

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.f
                 animations:^{
                     compassDial.center = CGPointMake(160, 504-92);
                     pushView.center = CGPointMake(160, 500-92);
                     //directionsArrow.center = CGPointMake(160, 502-92);
                 } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                     directionsArrow.hidden = NO;
                     [locationManager startUpdatingHeading];
                 }];
```

**In locationManager:**

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateHeading:(CLHeading *)newHeading{
float oldRadian = (-manager.heading.trueHeading * M_PI/180.0f);
float newRadian = (-newHeading.trueHeading * M_PI/180.0f);

CABasicAnimation *animation;
        animation=[CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation"];
animation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:oldRadian];
animation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:newRadian];
animation.duration = 0.5f;

[directionsArrow.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"animateMyRotation"];
directionsArrow.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(newRadian);
```

**Dismiss:**

```
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.f
    animations:^{
                compassDial.center = CGPointMake(160, 700); 
                directionsArrow.center = CGPointMake(160, 700);

                 } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                   [locationManager stopUpdatingHeading];
                 }];
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You probably want to call `[locationManager stopUpdateHeading];` after the animations have finished... Also talking about the syntax used for animating - "Use of this method is discouraged in iOS 4.0 and later. You should use the block-based animation methods to specify your animations instead."

Comment: What's the question? You made a bunch of statements and posted some code but never said what the actual problem is.

Comment: The question is: if i make one animation, the other animation stops, how do i make it possible for both to run after each other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming the two animations you want to happen at the same time are the rotation and the moving of the frame?

The easiest thing to do to ensure the animation is smooth and follows what you expect is to place the compass inside another view.

You can then animate the frame of the compass' parent to make the compass move in and out and apply the rotation just to the compass itself.

Show

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.f
                 animations:^{
                   compassContainer.center = CGPointMake(160, 410);
                 }];
```

Rotation

```
// The code you already have changing the transform of directionsArrow
```

Dismiss

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.f
                 animations:^{
                   compassContainer.center = CGPointMake(160, 410);
                 } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                   [locationManager stopUpdateHeading];
                 }];
```

Comment: Nothing for [locationManager startUpdateHeading]?

Comment: still the same thing. it stops updating and doesnt start again even if i put the start command in the show-statements you sent. the locationManager just don't want to start updating or animating again.

Comment: everything runs smoother now, though. :)

Comment: That's probably a different question and we would most likely need to see the code for how you are starting/stoping the location manager

Comment: i put a nslog to see what happens. " NSLog(@"%f (%f) => %f (%f)", manager.heading.trueHeading, oldRad, newHeading.trueHeading, newRad); 
". Everything is working 'til i dismiss, and when i show it again it doesnt start again updating again, even though i added [locationManager startUpdatingHeading]; to it... any ideas?

Comment: The method is - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateHeading:(CLHeading *)newHeading{

Comment: Is `locationManager` non nil at the point where you call `startUpdatingHeading` again?

Comment: seems like it doesn't even continue updating if i never stop updating the heading... when the animation to hide/show is committed, the animation that moves the compass needle stops and i can't start it again.

Comment: You are still setting the `directionsArrow.center` in the dismiss part this is not right

Answer (score 1):

As Paul.s mentioned in the comments, that is not the current preferred way to do animations. And what you ask is really quite easy with the block method of animations. Have a look at the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIView/animateWithDuration%3aanimations%3acompletion%3a), and here is a short example.

```
-(IBAction)animateDelete:(id)sender
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.4 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn
                     animations:^{
                         // Your first animation here...
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                         // Do some stuff
                         [UIView animateWithDuration:0.4 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                                          animations:^{
                                              // Your second animation here...
                                          }
                                          completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                                              // Do some stuff
                                          }
                          ];
                     }
    ];
}
```